# unsquashing a liveUSB, I found that the filesystem is not identical to the one loaded from liveUSB

Tags: boot, filesystem, live-usb, lightdm, squashfs

so I have ubuntu studio 64 in a live USB and I wanted to change the way it boots. Namely, the liveUSB boots directly to a `live user session` bypassing `lightDM`. I want to change that and as I figured out, under `/etc/lightDM/lightdm.conf`, there are some `autologin-*` options that need removing.

Of course, this being a liveUSB, the root filesystem is just a copy-on-ram of the squashed filesystem that resides in a file in the usb drive. So just altering the value in `/etc/lightDM/lightdm.conf` would not suffice.

I used [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80305/mounting-a-squashfs-filesystem-in-read-write) guide to get the squash filesystem. Once I unsquashed it and navigated to `<squashfs-root>/etc/lightdm`, to my surprise I saw a different set of files. namely

```
$ ls -l
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 nass nass 4096 Ιαν   2 06:00 lightdm.conf.d
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nass nass   55 Ιαν   2 05:53 lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf -> /etc/alternatives/lightdm-gtk-greeter-config-derivative
-rw-r--r-- 1 nass nass 1317 Μάρ  13  2014 lightdm-gtk-greeter-ubuntu.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 nass nass  456 Απρ  11  2014 users.conf
```

so the most obvious surprise is that there is no `lightdm.conf`. So where is it? where should I change it in order for the change to have an effect?

thank you

Comment: I don't know how to exactly change it the way you want, however, I can tell you that lightdm.conf was depreciated at 14.04 and we now use the individual files in lightdm.conf.d instead.

Comment: do you have a file called /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/12-autologin.conf? if so delete this file. If not, check the file: /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/10-ubuntustudio.conf and delete the line "autologin-user="

Comment: Hi @mchid. The latter file you suggest exists, but contains `user-session=ubuntu-studio` only. there are no other files containing any of the `autologin-*` statements.

Comment: @mchid ... and I have now rebuilt the filesystem and the `autologin-*` statements are still there... arghhh!